# Fast nearest neighbour search using Parse as backend

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So I have to implement a nearest neighbor search feature on my app, and I am currently using Parse as the backend. What I was doing till now was to perform a query and get the results and then sort them to get the top 20-30 results. But since my database has scaled up, I now have about 4,000 locations (expect to reach about 15,000) on which I have to apply the nearest neighbor search. This is not good for a real time system.

**What I have thought of:**

1. I can code an efficient solution using QuadTree, but here's a catch. I understand that I can make a job and create the QuadTree and keep it in memory, but this seems wasteful as there always will be a complete thread devoted to maintaining the tree in the memory, not to mention constant checking and balancing. And in the event that thread fails, I will probably have to manually start it.
2. The other solution could be to create a QuadTree object and store it in stable memory, and read that object everytime the query comes in, and serve the results. But I think this will be slow too.

How should I solve this problem? Or should I try another BaaS, or make a custom API using AWS or AppEngine? I really don't want the hassle of managing load and security features at this point, as this is a non-profit project.

Comment: You mean nearest neighbour for what? GeoPoints? Custom objects?

Comment: For GeoPoints. I have Lat and Long values from Gmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave this job to Parse, there is no need to search your objects manually. Once you have your `lat` and `lon` coordinates simply create `ParseGeoPoint` object

```
ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(lat, lon);
```

and the use this query to get 30 nearest objects

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClass");
query.whereNear("location", point);
query.setLimit(30);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { ... });
```

The query result is an `ArrayList` sorted from nearest to farthest objects.

Read the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints) of `ParseGeoPoint` for detailed info.

Comment: I used a similar approach, but processed the GeoPoint at server-side (there is a .near() JS function that does that). Thanks for suggesting the approach.